# Android- Tab mode actionbar with overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have an app with no home/title bar, and an actionbar in tab navigation mode. I've added a menu to my app, which I want to show in Android 4+ as an overflow menu in the tab actionbar.

It sounds well and simple, but when I add the menu

```
    // Initiating menu XML file
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

// Event handling for individual menu item selected
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_search:
        // Load search fragment
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_add:
        // Load add fragment
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I get this in landscape view, which is good:

[image]

But I get this in portrait mode, which is bad:

[image]

How do I prevent the tab actionbar from splitting in portrait mode?

**EDIT:** So it appears that when a menu is created in android 4, it immediately becomes an action overflow menu in the activity's titlebar. The problem is, I don't have a titlebar, just a tab navigation actionbar. So the activity creates a new title/action bar with an action overflow option.

I need to find a way to make the activity add the action overflow tab to the tab navigation actionbar. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I too have the same issue

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do this as well, but it seems the actionbar overflow menu is not meant to be tinkered with. One hackish way of doing it would be to create a third tab that acts as the menu button, haven't tried it though.